# Dealing with $(this) element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple input fields on my page and want to update the text of the label for the particular input field selected. I want to display the filename that has been uploaded

I have come up with this but it changes the label for the first instance of the input field no matter which one i select

```js
$('.document_file_field').on('change', function() {
  var input_field = $(this)
  var fileName = input_field[0].files[0]['name']
  $(this).prev('.custom-file-upload').text(fileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="custom-file-upload btn btn-info" for="document_media">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
    Upload Document
  </label>
  <input class="document_file_field" type="file" name="document[media]" id="document_media" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
<form>
  <label class="custom-file-upload btn btn-info" for="document_other">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
    Upload Document
  </label>
  <input class="document_file_field" type="file" name="document[media]" id="document_other" />
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

How can i make this work so that I am only dealing with the input_field and its label in question

Thanks

Comment: You could try using `function(event)' and `event.target' instead.

Comment: Make sure your IDs are unique.

Comment: Please see the snippet that I added to your question. Seems to work just fine there, so this problem is not reproducible. Can you provide us a code sample that actually demonstrates the problem? And it doesn't seem that duplicate IDs are the problem because I tried it with duplicate IDs too.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way is to use the selector based on the `for` attribute:

```
var $input = $(this), id = $input.attr("id");
$input.prev('label[for="' + id + '"]').text(fileName);
```

This assumes each label references a uniquely Id input

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/7gLnya31/

first make sure you have unique Ids. then you can search for the label element with the for attribute having the value same as the id of the file input changed.

```
$('.document_file_field').on('change', function(){
  var input_field = $(this)
  var inputId=input_field.attr('id')
  var fileName = input_field[0].files[0]['name'];
    $('label[for='+inputId+']').text(fileName);

});
```